# How to create a new column in dataframe A, based on multiple conditions in dataframe B

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-conditions

I guess I don´t see the forest through the trees... Thus, I would like to ask for help.

**Data:** for dput() output see at the end of the question.

> ```
> -Dataframe dfA with the columns: ID; ts. ts being POSIXct
>
> -Dataframe dfB with the columns: ID; start; end; state_id. ID (corresponding to the ID in dfA), start (POSIXct), end (POSIXct), state_id.
> ```

**The task:**

I would like to create a new column in dfA with values 1/0 based on a condition. The condition in words: If the ID in dfA and dfB matches, and if the timestamp dfA$ts is in between or equal to dfB$start and dfB$end, then the value 1 should be written into dfA$x, otherwise a 0 should be there.

I think the code should look somewhat like this:

> ```
> dfA$x <- iflese( dfA$ID == dfB$ID & dfA$ts >= dfB$start & dfA$ts <= dfB$end, 1, 0)
> ```

Thanks for the help already in advance.

**dput(dfB):**

> structure(list(ID = c(1151L, 1151L, 1150L, 1150L, 1150L, 1150L,
> 1152L, 1152L, 1152L, 1345L), start = structure(c(1443142500,
> 1443144600, 1442934900, 1442942400, 1442944800, 1442946300, 1443103500,
> 1443132600, 1443137400, 1443389400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
> )), end = structure(c(1443143400, 1443145500, 1442935500, 1442943000,
> 1442945400, 1442950200, 1443106200, 1443134100, 1443140100, 1443392400
> ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), state_id = c(1L, 2L, 1L,
> 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

**dput(dfA):**

> structure(list(ID = c(1151L, 1151L, 1151L, 1151L, 1151L, 1151L,
> 1151L, 1151L, 1151L, 1151L, 1151L, 1151L, 1151L, 1151L, 1151L,
> 1151L, 1151L, 1151L, 1151L, 1151L, 1150L, 1150L, 1150L, 1150L,
> 1150L, 1150L, 1150L, 1150L, 1150L, 1150L, 1150L, 1150L, 1152L,
> 1152L, 1152L, 1152L, 1152L, 1152L, 1152L, 1152L, 1152L, 1152L,
> 1152L, 1152L, 1152L, 1152L, 1152L, 1152L, 1345L, 1345L, 1345L,
> 1345L, 1345L, 1345L, 1345L, 1345L, 1345L, 1345L), ts = structure(c(1443141300,
> 1443141600, 1443141900, 1443142200, 1443142500, 1443142800, 1443143100,
> 1443143400, 1443143700, 1443144000, 1443144300, 1443144600, 1443144900,
> 1443145200, 1443145500, 1443145800, 1443146100, 1443146400, 1443146700,
> 1443147000, 1442934900, 1442935200, 1442935500, 1442935800, 1442936100,
> 1442936400, 1442936700, 1442937000, 1442937300, 1442937600, 1442937900,
> 1442938200, 1443103500, 1443103800, 1443104100, 1443104400, 1443104700,
> 1443105000, 1443105300, 1443105600, 1443105900, 1443106200, 1443106500,
> 1443106800, 1443107100, 1443107400, 1443107700, 1443108000, 1443369300,
> 1443369600, 1443369900, 1443370200, 1443370500, 1443370800, 1443371100,
> 1443371400, 1443371700, 1443372000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
> ))), row.names = c(NA, -58L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an updating non-equi join:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dfA); setDT(dfB)

dfA[dfB, match := 1, on=.(ID=ID, ts>=start, ts<=end)][, match:=ifelse(is.na(match), 0, match)]
```

---

```
      ID                  ts match
 1: 1151 2015-09-25 07:35:00     0
 2: 1151 2015-09-25 07:40:00     0
 3: 1151 2015-09-25 07:45:00     0
 4: 1151 2015-09-25 07:50:00     0
 5: 1151 2015-09-25 07:55:00     1
 6: 1151 2015-09-25 08:00:00     1
 7: 1151 2015-09-25 08:05:00     1
 8: 1151 2015-09-25 08:10:00     1
 9: 1151 2015-09-25 08:15:00     0
10: 1151 2015-09-25 08:20:00     0
...
```

Comment: Your solution works best as I am using large datasets. Also very fast (0.16 sec)...       Yet, a follow up question. If I would like to add the state_id column as well, I figured it should work through: dfA[dfB, state_ID := state_id, on=.(ID=ID, ts>=start, ts<=end)]     For the small example dataset it is working. For the real dataset I get the wrong numbers. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe check again carefully. If you're 100% sure that the numbers are not matching correctly, then you'll have to provide a minimal dataset for me (or others) to test. I know your dataset is large, but perhaps subset the ids that are not working? Also, check for duplicates on ID + ts (dfA) and ID+start (dfB).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data.table`, conditional replacement with `:=`:

```r
data.table::setDT(dfA)
dfA[,value := 0L]
dfA[(get('ID') == dfB$ID) & (get('ts') >= dfB$start) & (get('ts') <= dfB$end), value := 1L]
```

Note that I put column names from dfA in a `get` call to avoid confusion with `dfB` columns.

In this situation `dfA` and `dfB` must have the same number of rows. If they don't, use a `merge` based on `ID` column

Comment: dfA and dfB don´t have the same number of rows. Merging by ID doesn´t solve the problem, as there is multiple rows in dfA as well as in dfB which would be merged. This means duplicate values in ID in dfA and dfB.

Answer (score 0):

We can `left_join` `dfA` and `dfB` by `'ID'`, `group_by` each `ID` and `ts` and check if `any` value lies in the range for that group.

```
library(dplyr)

dfA %>%
  left_join(dfB, by = 'ID') %>%
  group_by(ID, ts) %>% 
  summarise(x = +any(ts >= start & ts <= end))


#      ID ts                      x
#   <int> <dttm>              <int>
# 1  1150 2015-09-22 23:15:00     1
# 2  1150 2015-09-22 23:20:00     1
# 3  1150 2015-09-22 23:25:00     1
# 4  1150 2015-09-22 23:30:00     0
# 5  1150 2015-09-22 23:35:00     0
# 6  1150 2015-09-22 23:40:00     0
# 7  1150 2015-09-22 23:45:00     0
# 8  1150 2015-09-22 23:50:00     0
# 9  1150 2015-09-22 23:55:00     0
#10  1150 2015-09-23 00:00:00     0
# … with 48 more rows
```

Comment: Your solution is working for a small example dataset as the one I gave here. Yet, with the whole dataset I get the following error: Error: std::bad_alloc. . I think it must be due to the size of my data.frame. It was also the supposed issue for others with this error:  https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/150

Comment: @RasK I am not sure about that. It works for the data shared here so I cannot test it for other datasets.